# All the small primes close together yet again

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

$$
\begin{align}
2254 & = 2\cdot7\cdot7\cdot23 \\
2255 & = 5\cdot11\cdot41 \\
2256 & = 2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot3\cdot47 \\
2257 & = 37\cdot61 \\
2258 & = 2\cdot1129 \\
2259 & = 3\cdot3\cdot251 \\
2260 & = 2\cdot2\cdot5\cdot113 \\
2261 & = 7\cdot17\cdot19 \\
2262 & = 2\cdot3\cdot13\cdot29 \\
2263 & = 31\cdot73 \\
2264 & = 2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot283 \\
2265 & = 3\cdot5\cdot151 \\
2266 & = 2\cdot11\cdot103 
\end{align}
$$
I [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73763/small-primes-attract-large-primes) I pointed something out, of which the foregoing is another instance.

The integer parts of the square roots of all of these numbers are equal to $47$, which is the $15$th prime, so if we're checking for primality, we need to search that far and the rest does itself.  Now notice which primes $\le47$ appear above:
$$
2,\,3,\,5,\,7,\,11,\,13,\,17,\,19,\,23,\,29,\,31,\,37,\,41,\,\bullet,\,47
$$
i.e. all of those first $15$ **except** $43$.  Hence nearby numbers can be divisible only by small primes that recur frequently or primes bigger than the square root of the number being factored.  (In particular $2272$ is $71$ times a power of $2$, and $2268$ has no prime factors bigger than $7$.)

**Is there any reasonable sense it which it could be said that we shouldn't find it so surprising that this---all those early primes occurring so close together---occurs among numbers as small as these?  Should we expect frequent instances of this?**

**PS:** "Small" should probably be taken to mean these numbers are not much bigger than $47^2=2209$, where, remember, $47$ is the biggest prime number $\le$ the square roots of these numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you acknowledge, your example is imperfect in that your set $S=\{2254,\dots,2266\}$ lacks a multiple of 43. If we take $p_i=53$, then, to cover all primes $q<p_i$ with a range of consecutive integers not all less than $p_{i-1}{}^2=47^2=2209$, we need 16 integers, and the range $\{2664,\dots,2679\}$ will do.

To investigate further, for each prime $p=p_i$ I found that range of $k=k(p)$ consecutive integers $\{n-k+1,\dots,n\}$ that covers all primes $q<p$, minimising $k(p)$, subject to $n\geqslant p_{i-1}{}^2$.

There are 1229 primes $p<10000$. For 258 of them, or about 21%, $k(p)$ sets a new record high for $k$. Below I list the results for a few of these, where $k(p)/p$ also set a record high for $k/p$.

$\begin{array}{rrrrr}
p&k&n-k+1&n&k/p\\
43&14&1763&1776&0.326\\
103&52&10184&10235&0.505\\
241&161&56970&57130&0.668\\
509&358&254472&254829&0.703\\
1013&783&1023703&1024485&0.773\\
2113&1807&4456626&4458432&0.855\\
5101&4476&25996157&26000632&0.877\\
9241&8441&85369195&85377635&0.913
\end{array}$

There is a general trend upwards in $k/p$. Below is another selection where this time I selected some of those $p$ where $k(p)/p$ is less than all later $k(q)/q$ for all $q>p$ within the scope of my program run:

$\begin{array}{rrrrr}
p&k&n-k+1&n&k/p\\
17&3&285&287&0.176\\
53&16&2664&2679&0.302\\
101&37&9699&9735&0.366\\
229&109&51900&52008&0.476\\
557&301&307268&307568&0.540\\
1031&709&1049190&1049898&0.688\\
2237&1606&4966944&4968549&0.718\\
5011&4084&25093284&25097367&0.815
\end{array}$

Your $p=53$ is among these! Even though making an $S$ which covers *all* primes $q<53$ needed $k=16$, somewhat more than your example which lacked 43, $k(53)=16$ gives $k/p\approx0.302$ which turns out to be a record low.

Whether $\liminf_{p\to\infty} k(p)/p=1$ I daren't say, but it appears that way. At any rate, once $p$ gets into the thousands, *every* prime $p$ needs a sequence $S$ which has (as a proportion) nearly $p$ terms.